# How to show total quantity on front end product page?

Tags: inventory, magento-2.1.7

Sorry I am totally new to Magento and cannot seem to figure out where exactly to add this code. I added on top and got the following result. It just shows the code. Can you please help?

https://merchantscanada.biz/hp-6300-pro-core-i5-desktop.html

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Andreas will help for Magento 1.

Depending on where you want to show the quantity, the easiest thing in my opinion is to check which template file generates the area, and then override it in your own theme and add the quantity.

The original modules can be found, depending on your install, either in `app/code/Magento` or in `vendor/magento`. The templates for the product view page can be found in the Catalog-module.

If this is all new to you - you should start here: http://devdocs.magento.com/ :)

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks much for the reply. Basically what I am trying to accomplish here is to create a simple catalog that shows all the products with total quantity in stock with no pricing. Brand new Magento 2.17 installation, using default Luna theme. Few test products created yet. I have very little development experience and can follow basic instructions. We are suing open cart at the moment but am trying my best to switch to Magento if I can,

Comment: Hi, actually Magento, and Magento 2 even more than 1, is not an easy system - especially for non-developers. You should really read the docs I mentioned above, and hire a Magento agency if you don't get it ;) believe me, shops programmed by devs new to Magento won't make the owner happy most of the time. This said, it is a difference if this is the only product page in the shop - then you can just modify the category template. Or if there should also be "normal" category pages, then you will have to create a small module to get the product collection and show it with a special template

Comment: Thank you kindly for the helpful information. I will read through the documentation you pointed out to figure it out. We don't need anything except displaying products with quantity. That is all. NO users, no cart, no shipping etc. I have pretty much configured everything else and the only two missing bits are to hide the price and display total quantity available in stock. I will spend some more time over the weekend to get it worked.

Comment: Way don't you use sth like WordPress? Oo